# Trying to undo a cleartool rm

Tags: clearcase

I was trying to migrate a file from directory A to directory B in a branch, call it file.txt. What I did was:

```
cd A
cp file.txt ../B/
ct rm A
cd ../B
ct mkelem -ci -nc file.txt
```

Thereby losing all the history. I am trying to recover from this to do what I should have done which is simply `ct mv file.txt ../B`

I read that for this I should do something like this:

```
cd A
ct ln .@@/main/?/file.txt ./file.txt
```

where luckily, from another view, I've figured out `?` should be 27. Unfortunately when I try to do the above I get:

```
cleartool: Error: Entry named "file.txt" already exists.
cleartool: Error: Unable to create link: "./file.txt".
```

and I try to do:

```
ct rmelem file.txt
```

but got:

```
cleartool: Error: Element "file.txt" has branches not created by user
```

though presumably that's not what I should be doing anyway. How do I get back that file? It was simply a `ct rm`. I even get the entry already exists error if I do `ct rm` on the new copy file I added to directory B..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but I would recommend a simple **[`rmname`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm)**, instead of a [`rmelem`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmelem.htm) (which deletes the element with all its versions, branches and such).

That would remove `file.txt` from the latest version of the parent directory, and allows you to proceed with the symlink.

Next time, a [`cleartool mv`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm) might be easier, and keep the history of the file being moved.