# How to run clearfsimport command for similar streams

Tags: clearcase

I have two streams

```
Int 
 |--> Dev
```

I want to make sure `Dev` has everything similar to Int stream word to word.
I have already rebased `Dev` stream from `Int` stream, but I know its not going to make it exact replica of Int.

I know I should be using "`clearfsimport`" command but I could not understand whats the syntax for it.

Please help me with the command using below assumptions,  I am on solaris and will be using cleartool command line interface

- project vob directory - `/vobs/HowDoI`
- Stream name -> `HowdoI_Int`
- `Int` View name -> `HowDoI_int_View`
- Dev Stream name -> `HowDoI_Dev`
- Dev View name -> `HowDoI_Dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)" for an example of [`clearfsimport` syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm).

In your case, assuming both views are started, and the vob is mounted:

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -rmname -nset /view/HowDoI_int_View/vobs/HowDoI /view/HowDoI_dev_View/vobs/HowDoI
```

Remove the `-preview` when you think the command does what you think it should.

Note the `-rmname` option in order to get a mirror image from Int to Dev:
Any element present in `Dev` which are *not* present in `Int` will be `rmname` from `Dev`, leaving it *exactly* as `Int` (meaning without *extra* elements)

> Error: Must be set to an activity in a UCM view.

That means you must [set an activity first](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm) in the *destination* view (the one in which you are importing files):

```
cd /view/HowDoI_dev_View/vobs/HowDoI
cleartool mkact import_deom_int
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, I tried it but I am getting this error

clearfsimport -preview -rec -rmname -nset /view/XXXX_Proj_Int_View/vobs/pvob /view/XXXX_Dev_3_View/vobs/pvob

clearfsimport: Error: Must be set to an activity in a UCM view.

Comment: @bhagyesh.shah right, I have edited the answer to address that error message.

Comment: You don't really mean `rmelem`, do you?

Comment: @aschepler sorry, I meant `rmname`, not `rmelem`. I have edited the answer. I only use `rmelem` in `lost+found` directory (like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4941527/6309), otherwise, I avoid it if possible and use `rmname` (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325977/6309).