# branching from multiple files in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

I have around 5000 files for which i have to create a branch(say my_branch) from main branch,checkout those files,check in and then apply label.
Its practically impossible to seperately create branch for each file and do the other steps.
There is a way to apply common label to all checkout files and check in all checked out files..that reduces my work but is there a way to create branch for 5000 files with just one cmd or are there any tool to do so

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a snapshot view ready to create that branch for you, meaning with a config spec like:

```
element * .../myBranch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch myBranch
element /main/0 -mkbranch myBranch
```

(assuming here that your files are for now on `/main`)

In that case, what you do is:

- copy and update your 5000 files somewhere else
- clearfsimport them into your snapshot view: 5000 files will be checked out, updated, checked-in in the right branch for you, one by one, automatically.
  See "[How to run clearfsimport command for similar streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070750/6309)" as an example for the `clearfsimport` command.