# Some redundant codes in a VOB in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

There is a folder `A`, and there are few files inside `A`:

```
f1 
f2 
f3 .....
```

Now there is another folder inside `A` by name `x`.
Inside `x` also we have some files with the same name as

```
f1 
f2 
f3 
f4 ....
```

- The files inside `A` has 4 versions
- and `f1 f2 f3 f3` in `x` also has 7 versions each

We found that these `f1` in both `A` and `X` are the same files.

So now we need to move all 7 versions `f1 f2 f3` under `x` to `A` and added it as 5th version under `A` folder.

Do we need to raise a SR with IBM to understand whether it is possible or not?
If it is possible, how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a **[`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070750/6309)** of `x` folder into `A`: that will automatically update `A` files version, adding a 5th version to `fn` in A with the content of `fn` in `x`.

Note that it will ignore the first 6th version of `fn` in `x`: it will take only the current content of `fn` from `x`, automatically checkout `fn` in `A`, create a new version and check in `fn` in `A`.

```
clearfsimport -preview -rec -nset /path/to/x /path/to/yourView/path/to/A
```

**Caveat**: That would be done with a full ClearCase installation, not a CCRC one (7.x), as [CCRC as no clearfsimport capability](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358355).

If you don't have too many files and only access to CCRC, you can do it manually through a CCRC web view: checkout all common files, copy files from `X` to `A`, checkin all common files.

But if you do have many files, you need to ask your ClearCase admin: the CCRC server is based on a full ClearCase installation, and does have the `clearfsimport` utility available.